# Do I need a table alias while using same table in multiple subqueries

Tags: sql

Do I need to use different table aliases if I plan to use a table in multiple subqueries? Or can I just call the table in each subquery and they won't interfere with eachother because they are in a subquery?

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide an example of what you are talking about.  It is not clear what your question means.

Comment: It could be a good idea to have different table aliases for each instance, however not required.

Comment: Sub queries are usually works as isolated queries in background, you can still use same alias. But it is always good practice to use different aliases for sub-query and actual query

Answer (score 1):

Within any particular subquery, table names/aliases that are in scope are those names/aliases introduced by that subquery and any names and aliases from outer queries<sup>1</sup>.

Two subqueries introduced at the same "level" will not see the names/aliases of each other.

That being said, it's usually better to use distinct names where possible just to reduce confusion.

E.g.

```
SELECT
    *,
    (select a from table2 t2 where t1.id = t2.id) a,
    (select b from table3 t3 where t1.id = t3.id) b
from
    table1 t1
       inner join
    (select id,c from table4 t4) t4x
       on
          t1.id = t4.id
       cross apply
    (select d from table5 t5 where t5.id = t4x.id) t5x
```

The subquery on `table4` cannot see any of `table1`, `table2`, `table3` or their aliases without introducing them itself into its from clause (and in such a case, the new references are distinct from the outer references even if the alises are reused).

The subqueries on `table2` and `table3` can each see `t1` and `t5`, but the `table2` subquery cannot see `t3` and the `table3` subquery cannot see `t2`.

The subquery on `table5` can reference `t1` and `t4x`.

All of tables 1-5 could in fact be the same table, it doesn't affect the above.

---

<sup>1</sup>Subqueries introduced as table sources within the `FROM` clause of an outer query cannot generally reference any tables from the outer query though, unless introduced by a `APPLY` in which case the names that are in scope are the names from the outer query that are forming part of the result set to which the `APPLY` is being... applied.

Answer (score 0):

suppose a table name is table1

now if write your query like below

```
select t1.col1 from table1 t1 join table1 t2 on t1.col1=t2.col2
```

so in the above i used self join and there is no way without alias

but if query like below

```
select t1.* from 
(
select col1,col2 from table1 --inner query no need alias but it is a good practice to use alias 
) as t1 -- here also you have to use alias which is actually outer query name
```